# inspecting a buffer through struct

Tags: c, struct

I am novice on the topic, I have `unsinged char *buffer`

I am trying to inspect it at 3 bytes at a time

I think maybe this can be solved with a 2 dimensional array.

so I tried this -

```
unsigned char *bytes[3] = {};
*bytes = buffer;
```

but I see that's a notation to create array of 3 elements of type `unsigned char *`

is there any way to achieve this without having to `memcpy`

any pointers are greatly appreciated.

this approach seems to work

```
typedef struct utf8 {
    unsigned char bytes[3];
};

typedef struct utf8 utf8x;

utf8x *xx = (utf8x *) buffer; //buffer is a return from fread (unsinged char *)

if (xx->bytes[0] == 0xe0) {
   printf("scratch");
}
```

however I am still trying to figure out how to compare all the bytes, I guess if I cast xx->bytes to return 3 bytes it should work.

Comment: Try to tighten up your question.  It's rambling and unclear now.  You never explain or give an example of what a "table lookup" is in this context.

Comment: @JohnZwinck reduced it to scope

Comment: i took the lookup table reference out since its not a primitive matter in this context, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Ryan let me updated, i made a reference to it on top. sorry

Comment: Why not just use a pointer? `unsigned char* fifth_triple = &buff[3 * 4]; if (fifth_triple[0] == 0xe0) {`

Comment: is therre anyway to compare `*pointer == 0x000000` (3 bytes) @Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compare three bytes of a buffer at once.  You can do this using `memcmp()` (which a good compiler will optimize out so there is no actual function call).  For example:

```
utf8x *xx = (utf8x *) buff;

if (memcmp(&xx->bytes[0], "\100\50\10", 3) == 0) {
   printf("scratch");
}
```

That will print `scratch` if the first three bytes are `\100 \50 \10`.

Comment: ah ok thanks john, so the key is `memcmp` ok thank you very much! so the struct it self can't litmit the comparison without using memcmp?